# How to capture soft keyboard input in a View?

Tags: android

I have a subclassed View that pops up the keyboard when it receives a 'touch up' in onTouchEvent.  It shows this by requesting focus, retrieving the InputMethodManager, and then calling showSoftInput.

Now I need to figure out how to capture the tapped letters of the soft keyboard, *as they are pressed*.  I am currently only getting a response when the Next/Done button is pressed on the soft keyboard.

Here is my class:

```
public class BigGrid extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "BigGrid";

    public BigGrid(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true); // allows the keyboard to pop up on
                                       // touch down

        setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onKeyListener");
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "onTOUCH");
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            // show the keyboard so we can enter text
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateInputConnection");

        BaseInputConnection fic = new BaseInputConnection(this, true);
        outAttrs.actionLabel = null;
        outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
        outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT;
        return fic;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckIsTextEditor");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(R.color.grid_bg);
        // .
        // .
        // alot more drawing code...
        // .
    }
}
```

The keyboard shows, but my onKeyListener only fires when I press the 'Next' button on the keyboard.  I need which character is tapped, so that I can display it in my onDraw() method.

Comment: wouldn't it better to extend TextView?

Comment: Extending TextView doesn't give me any more control over listening for key events than what I already have (at least not that I am aware of), but what it does is some specific styling and text drawing that I would just have to override and get rid of.  That is why I chose to subclass View instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out that I did in fact need to subclass TextView and the use addTextChangedListener() to add my own implementation of TextWatcher in order to listen to soft key events.  I couldn't find a way to do this with a plain old View.

One other thing, for those who will try this technique; TextView is not able to edit text by default, so if you want to make your implementation editable (instead of subclassing EditText, which I didn't want to to do), you must also make a custom InputConnection, something like the following:

```
 /**
 * MyInputConnection
 * BaseInputConnection configured to be editable
 */
class MyInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection {
    private SpannableStringBuilder _editable;
    TextView _textView;

    public MyInputConnection(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(targetView, fullEditor);
        _textView = (TextView) targetView;
    }

    public Editable getEditable() {
        if (_editable == null) {
            _editable = (SpannableStringBuilder) Editable.Factory.getInstance()
            .newEditable("Placeholder");
        }
        return _editable;
    }

    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
        _editable.append(text);
        _textView.setText(text);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you override onCheckisTextEditor and onCreateInputConnection with something like the following:

```
 @Override
 public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
     outAttrs.actionLabel = null;
     outAttrs.label = "Test text";
     outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
     outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;

     return new MyInputConnection(this, true);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
     return true;
 }
```

After this, you should have a View that can listen to the soft keyboard and you can do whatever you want with the key input values.

Comment: While this may work in practice for most situations, I've recently learned (from one of the LatinIME developers) that a given IME can choose to add text to the Editable by invoking some of the other methods besides commitText().  The IME could use, for example, commitCompletion(), which will extend the current composing text.    So, you might want to look into overriding some additional methods, although your general approach is probably pretty good.

Answer (score 47):

It is actually possible to handle the key events yourself without deriving your view from TextView.

To do this, just modify your original code as follows:

1) Replace the following line in `onCreateInputConnection():`

```
outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
```

with this one:

```
outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL;
```

Per the documentation for `InputType.TYPE_NULL:`  "This should be interpreted to mean that the target input connection is not rich, it can not process and show things like candidate text nor retrieve the current text, so the input method will need to run in a limited 'generate key events' mode."

2) Replace the following line in the same method:

```
BaseInputConnection fic = new BaseInputConnection(this, true);
```

with this one:

```
BaseInputConnection fic = new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
```

The false second argument puts the BaseInputConnection into "dummy" mode, which is *also* required in order for the raw key events to be sent to your view.  In the BaseInputConnection code, you can find several comments such as the following: "only if dummy mode, a key event is sent for the new text and the current editable buffer cleared."

I have used this approach to have the soft keyboard send raw events to a view of mine that is derived from LinearLayout (i.e., a view not derived from TextView), and can confirm that it works.

Of course, if you didn't need to set the `IME_ACTION_DONE` imeOptions value to show a Done button on the keyboard, then you could just remove the `onCreateInputConnection()`  and `onCheckIsTextEditor()` overrides entirely, and raw events would then be sent to your view by default, since no input connection capable of more sophisticated processing would have been defined.

But unfortunately, there does not seem to be a simple way to configure the EditorInfo attributes without overriding these methods and providing a BaseInputConnection object, and once you have done that you will have to dumb down the processing performed by that object as described above if you want to once again receive the raw key events.

WARNING: Two bugs were introduced in certain recent versions of the default LatinIME keyboard that ships with Android (Google Keyboard) that can impact keyboard event processing (as described above) when that keyboard is in use.  I've devised some workarounds on the app side, with sample code, that appear to get around these problems.  To view these workarounds, see the following answer:

[Android - cannot capture backspace/delete press in soft. keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581636/android-cannot-capture-backspace-delete-press-in-soft-keyboard/19980975#19980975)

Comment: For those interested, one of the problems I'm dealing now is custom keyboards not honoring `InputType.TYPE_NULL`. Specifically, the Minuum keyboard seems completely oblivious of the setting, which breaks my app.

Comment: Also, and very importantly, the Samsung Keyboard distributed with the more recent Samsung Devices fails to implement this setting properly.  Specifically, it fails to suppress predictive text when TYPE_NULL is used.  If you turn off predictive text, it works fine with TYPE_NULL, but of course app users are not usually aware of this.

Comment: To hide this keyboard:  `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);`. There are few recommendations, this is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 27):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html), a `View` (editor) receives commands from the Keyboard (IME) through an [`InputConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html) and sends commands to the Keyboard through an [`InputMethodManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html).

[image]

I will show the entire code below, but here are the steps.

### 1. Make the Keyboard to appear

Since the view is sending a command to the keyboard it needs to use an `InputMethodManager`. For the sake of the example, we will say that when the view is tapped it will show the keyboard (or hide it if it is already showing).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The view also needs to have had `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` set previously.

### 2. Receive input from the keyboard

In order for the view to receive input from the keyboard, it needs to override `onCreateInputConnection()`. This returns the `InputConnection` that the Keyboard uses to communicate with the view.

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
    return new MyInputConnection(this, true);
}
```

The `outAttrs` specify what kind of keyboard the view is requesting. Here we are just requesting a normal text keyboard. Choosing `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` would display a number pad (if available). There are lots of other options. See [`EditorInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html).

You must return an [`InputConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html), which is usually a custom subclass of [`BaseInputConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.html). In that subclass you provide a reference to your editable string, which the keyboard will make updates to. Since a [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) implements the [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) interface, we will use that in our basic example.

```
public class MyInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection {

    private SpannableStringBuilder mEditable;

    MyInputConnection(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(targetView, fullEditor);
        MyCustomView customView = (MyCustomView) targetView;
        mEditable = customView.mText;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable getEditable() {
        return mEditable;
    }
}
```

All we did here was provide the input connection with a reference to the text variable in our custom view. The [`BaseInputConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.html) will take care of editing that `mText`. This could very well be all that you need to do. However, you can check out the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.java) and see which methods say "default implementation", especially "default implementation does nothing." These are other methods you may want to override depending on how involved your editor view is going to be. You should also look through all the method names in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.html). A number of them have notes to "editor authors". Pay special attention to those.

Some keyboards don't send certain input through the `InputConnection` for some reason (for example [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182401/3681880), enter, and some [number pad keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984968/3681880)). For those I added an `OnKeyListener`. Testing this setup on five different soft keyboards, everything seemed to work. Supplemental answers related to this are here:

- [Differentiating text keycode from control keycode in Android KeyEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982429/3681880)
- [Need table of key codes for android and presenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981419/3681880)
- [Input connection for numeric type keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984968/3681880)

### Full project code

Here is my full example for reference.

[image]

*MyCustomView.java*

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

    SpannableStringBuilder mText;

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mText = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        // handle key presses not handled by the InputConnection
        setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    if (event.getUnicodeChar() == 0) { // control character

                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                            mText.delete(mText.length() - 1, mText.length());
                            Log.i("TAG", "text: " + mText + " (keycode)");
                            return true;
                        }
                        // TODO handle any other control keys here
                    } else { // text character
                        mText.append((char)event.getUnicodeChar());
                        Log.i("TAG", "text: " + mText + " (keycode)");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // toggle whether the keyboard is showing when the view is clicked
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
        // outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER; // alternate (show number pad rather than text)
        return new MyInputConnection(this, true);
    }
}
```

*MyInputConnection.java*

```
public class MyInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection {

    private SpannableStringBuilder mEditable;

    MyInputConnection(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(targetView, fullEditor);
        MyCustomView customView = (MyCustomView) targetView;
        mEditable = customView.mText;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable getEditable() {
        return mEditable;
    }

    // just adding this to show that text is being committed.
    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
        boolean returnValue = super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
        Log.i("TAG", "text: " + mEditable);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.editorview.MainActivity">

    <com.example.editorview.MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is nothing special in the MainActivity.java code.

Please leave a comment if this doesn't work for you. I am using this basic solution for a custom EditText in a library I am making and if there are any edge cases in which it doesn't work, I want to know. If you would like to view that project, the custom view is [here](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library/blob/master/mongol-library/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/mongollibrary/MongolEditText.java). It's `InputConnection` is [here](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library/blob/master/mongol-library/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/mongollibrary/MetInputConnection.java).

### Related

- [How to make a custom system keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939816/3681880)
- [How to make a custom in-app keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45005691/3681880)

Comment: This code works well, excepting numbers input. CommitText is called for letters and symbols, but not for digits. I just uncommented line with TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and commented TYPE_CLASS_TEXT. Does anybody know, why it doesn't wirk?

Comment: @Suragch, thanks, it's good idea to use mEditable instead of callbacks. Also I found out that on numeric input sendKeyEvent is called instead of commitText.

Comment: @Serhii, Which keyboard are you testing this with? I should do it, too.

Comment: @Suragch, with standard soft keyboard

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that your `onKeyListener` is only going to get hardware keyboard key events.

You will get access to all input key events if you override `boolean View.onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

This way you can elect to handle the key event action `[ DOWN | MULTIPLE | UP ]` and return `true`, or allow the normal key processing to deal with it (`return super.onKeyPreIme()`)

Comment: I still need to try out onKeyPreIme, it looks like it may give me what I was looking for.  But, using a TextWatcher definitely works.