# How to get keyCode in android

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
tv.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         switch(keyCode) 
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Keycode_0");
                    return true;
                    //break;

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Keycode_1");
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Keycode_D");
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Keycode_2");
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Keycode_TAB");
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Keycode_DEL");
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_COMMA:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Keycode_COMMA");
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                    Log.v(TAG, "KEYCODE_ENTER");
                    i=KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER;
                    Log.v(TAG, "KEYCODE_ENTER"+i);
                    return true;
                    //break;
               case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT:
                    Log.v(TAG, "KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT"+KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT);
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT:
                    Log.v(TAG, "KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT"+KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT);
                    return true;
                    //break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
                    Log.v(TAG, "KEYCODE_SPACE"+KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE);
                    return true;
                    //break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it is working only for `enter` and `delete` keys. For the rest of the keys, it is not working. I wanted it for `shift` and `caps lock` keys.

Comment: Soft keyboards don't use the key codes for most things. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44342915/3681880

Answer (score 1):

Uset this listener on your editText:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Why You have commented the break statement. Please Uncomment the break statement and try.

Comment: it's not needed because of return statements