# How get accent KeyEvent code

Tags: android

To get a KeyEvent code I use KeyEvent like this:

```
int code = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A;
```

How I can get 'á' key code?

I try:

```
KeyEvent.getDeadChar('´', 'a');
```

But not works, this function returns acii code not KeyCode.

Comment: it seems to me like your are implementing a TextWatcher in a bad way, try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: No, I am trying to adapt an Android keyboard that does not have accents to one that have. I need do inject accent key when user press it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13510694/2826147

Comment: Read the link ip posted and the other one here

Comment: Some of the code I referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982429/3681880) touches on this.