# How to control input in EditText in Android?

Tags: android, input, crash

This is a two part question:

1) I'm currently using

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

to control the input in my app.

However, I keep getting crash reports from users with NumberFormatExceptions.
One of them was:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "2,7"
```

So clearly users are somehow circumventing my measures to control the input and using "," instead of ".". I've temporarily used

```
String.replace(",", ".")
```

in an attempt to fix it but I still get NumberFormatExceptions .

What do I do?

2) How do I force the soft keyboard app to display only a number pad, "-" and "."?

XML:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/speed"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" >
```

In Activity:

```
public void onClickCalc(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
              String sp = speed.getText().toString().replace(",", ".");
                if(functions.isNotValid(sp))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid input.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                float speed = Float.parseFloat(sp);

... logic here
}
```

In the class functions:

```
public static boolean isNotValid(String editable)
{
    try
    {
        float x = Float.parseFloat(editable);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nFE)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: could you please post your code where you are doing this??

Comment: Would capturing the key events work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419766/how-to-capture-soft-keyboard-input-in-a-view

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering to close this. Kenton Prince's reply's good.