# DispatchKeyEvent to listen for Spacebar being pressed

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project and I need to check when the spacebar is pressed sos I can execute a certain function.

The problem is, it was working on the emulator but not on my actual device. I think it might be because my emulator was using a physical keyboard, not the onscreen virtual keyboard but when testing on an actual device, its using a virtual keyboard.

I'm trying the dispatch keyevent

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            QueryEditor queryEditor = (QueryEditor)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_queryEditor);
            queryEditor.formatQueryText();
            return true;
        }
        }
```

I've also tried the on key down

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            disconnectDatabase();
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
        {
            QueryEditor queryEditor = (QueryEditor)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_queryEditor);
            queryEditor.formatQueryText();
        }
        
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Neither of these get fired though unless the back button is pressed but I need the spacebar to trigger the event.

### Update

Below is my code for how QueryEditor Fragment is created and the event handler is created

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        
        iQueryEditor = (IQueryEditor)this;
        iErrorHandler = (IErrorHandler)this;
        
        txtQueryEditor = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.query_txtQueryEditor);
        
        btnSubmitQuery = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.query_btnPerformQuery);
        btnClearQuery = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.query_btnDeleteQuery);
        
        txtQueryEditor.addTextChangedListener(new QueryTextChanged(getActivity(), txtQueryEditor, iQueryEditor));
        setDatabaseUsed();
        txtQueryEditor.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                {
                    executeQuery();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Space Bar Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        
        btnSubmitQuery.setOnClickListener(mBtnSubmitQueryListener);
        btnClearQuery.setOnClickListener(mBtnDeleteQueryListener);
    }
```

txtQueryEditor is the EditText that I am trying to receive the space bar event on.

Comment: The information in this question and its accepted answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419766/how-to-capture-soft-keyboard-input-in-a-view

Comment: Can you write how do you active soft keyboard to press space bar? Is it EditText view or is it done programatically? Where is the focus when you press space bar?

Comment: @Loop it is done by the user clicking inside the edit text that popups up keyboard and the user pressing the soft spacebar should trigger the event.

Comment: @Boardy take a look at my answer. I have explained how key events works and for your case the last part of code example will do the job. Just use proper listener as I presented.

Answer (score 7):

Part of the answer lies in the [KeyEvent API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html):

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on
>   receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular,
>   the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events
>   for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications
>   targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software
>   input methods may never send key events regardless of the version.
>   Consider using editor actions like IME_ACTION_DONE if you need
>   specific interaction with the software keyboard, as it gives more
>   visibility to the user as to how your application will react to key
>   presses.

Here is a [comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42904#c15) left by a Google Engineer:

> The answer is quite simple. Applications should *never* rely on key
>   events to manage user input. The reason for this is, it results in a
>   very poor user experience.
>
> To start with, there are too many cases where it does not work. It
>   does not work appropriately for CJK languages. It does not work
>   correctly with gesture input, or with voice input, or with toggle
>   input, or any new inventive input method developers may come up with
>   in the future. In fact, the only case where it works is for only
>   restricted cases of the poorest input experience : a legacy
>   hardware-keyboard-like input method, which is a poor fit for the
>   mobile era.
>
> This is why Android defines a rich API through which IMEs communicate
>   to the applications. It is method agnostic and language agnostic, and
>   all software input methods are implementing it. Applications are
>   supposed to make use of this API, and using EditText is the simplest
>   way of doing this (more on this below).
>
> Please stop relying on legacy key events for text entry -- AT ALL. It
>   is good to support them, but requiring them is bad for everyone. It
>   breaks consistency, it locks some languages out of your app, and it
>   forces users into a much poorer experience than they expect on
>   Android. And as noted in comment #14, input methods are explicitly
>   under no obligation at all to send key events, though some may choose
>   to do it.
>
> There are two simple ways of implementing the rich text input APIs.
>   Both will require some of this is done in Java land. The first one is
>   to simply use EditText. If your app needs to do its own rendering, you
>   can either subclass it if that suits you, or make it hidden while you
>   render any changes to the text. You could also use DynamicLayout and
>   Editable to achieve the same effect. Another possibility is to
>   implement directly the InputConnection API by extending
>   BaseInputConnection, however this is a *LOT* of hard work and should
>   generally only need to be done by applications that have very specific
>   needs with regards to text edition, like an IDE or a word processor.

Answer (score 4):

This implementation in your Activity should work:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("test", "[Dispatch] Space bar pressed! " + event);
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

The difference to your code is that I am calling `super.dispatchKeyEvent()` for all other keys than SPACE_BAR. If dispatchKeyEvent returns true `onKeyUp()` won't be triggered. So if you wish to just monitor space key event simply comment line `//return true;`

It would also works fine if you use `onKeyUp()` method. Do not use `onKeyDown()`, it may be called few times if user holds his finger too long.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        Log.d("test", "Space bar pressed!");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Here I use similar approach. If your if statement is true handle event and return true. For the rest of your keys call `super.onKeyUp();`

At least, but most important, if you have view(e.g. EditText) that owns current focus and keyboard is shown for that view then above code won't be called at all(in Activity). If this is the case you have to implement listener `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` and register for that view calling `setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener l)`.

```
viewWithFocus.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.d("test", "[Editor] Space bar pressed! " + event);
            //TODO implement your action here
            return true;//remove this line if you want edit text to create space
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

As alternative, you can override this view and implement `onKepUp()` like above.

**Update**

Above solution works for hardware keyboard. Sorry for not checking this more carefully.

From Android Documentation

> Note: When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and
>   related APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only
>   from a hardware keyboard. You should never rely on receiving key
>   events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).

However, I found how to overcome this problem. I have based my research on SearchView component and found that following code will do the job:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        char last = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        if (' ' == last) {
            Log.i("test", "space pressed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

For IME actions keep using `TextView.OnEditorActionListener`.

Comment: Thanks for your help I've tried this. It doesn't seem to be working for me though. I think I forgot to mention, don't know if its the reason, but the EditText is inside a fragment hosted by an activity. I've tried setting the event listener both via the fragment and via the activity but neither have fired the event

Comment: Can you paste more code? Especially where EditText being setup and XML file that use this EditText. TextView.OnEditorActionListener is definitely the right choice, you must be doing something else that blocks it.

Comment: @IllegalArgument After seeing your original answer I did not bother to look at it again. Do not accuse me unjustifiably.

Answer (score -1):

I tried both the methods dispatchkeyevents and onkeydown and for softkeyboard they didnot work. Atleast not in nexus 7. The only solution that worked was adding a textwatcher to the edittext. Below is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText editText1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String lastChar = s.toString().substring(s.length() - 1);
            if (lastChar.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "space bar pressed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}

}
```

Comment: your answer is terribly wrong. Key codes and actions are completely different things and they are not provided separately. Moreover, comparing keyCode value with ACTION_UP make no sense.