# How to make delete key- delete all selected edit text in custom android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, inputconnection

I am creating custom android keyboard and I want delete key to delete all the edit text if they are selected.

i.e, when text is selected, clipboard(cut,copy,paste comes up); in that mode , if the delete key is pressed, it should delete all. It doesn't currently.

P.S don't tell me for a specific edit text, it is a custom keyboard, it won't have access to edit text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it won't. In the keyboard, I created, I just send out the delete key event and it works like a charm. Try the following when delete/backspace key is pressed while something is selected.

```
getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
```

Comment: When I was making a custom Editor I forgot that I had to handle the delete as `KeyEvent`. That makes sense that I have to also send it as a key event from the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can also see if the `InputConnection` has any selected text with [`getSelectedText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#getSelectedText(int)). Then delete it if it does (or delete the preceding character if it doesn't).

```
CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
    inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
} else {
    inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
}
```

Comment: but don't forget about emoji