# How to Open Android Soft Keyboard (Numeric) Programmatically ?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, programmatically-created, numeric-keypad

I know how to open a soft keyboard and even handle its key events. I need to open **Numeric** keyboard.

**P.S** I am **not** using **Edittexts** in layout file.

Here is the code I am using to open keyboard programmatically

```
    if (PasscodeLockUpdated.this != null) {
    PasscodeLockUpdated.this .getWindow()
    .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);}
```

Comment: So how did you solve it? I am trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @KartikKaushik I had to make a custom keyboard of my own in form of a fragment and communicate with it with callbacks and now whenever i need it, i just pop it up on the screen with a sliding animation.

Comment: Thanks @Shahroz, I also made my own keyboard using tableLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding an EditText programmatically? If so, you can change the `InputType` (as you would if you had xml) in java using:

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | **Another type if you want more than one**);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No I am not using edittext at all. I want to fill the textviews with default keyboard input.

Comment: Well, that clears that up. Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5684661/716588) to a similar question? This answer uses a `class MyInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection` to capture input from the keyboard and `setText` a `TextView`.

Comment: Sorry, I've deviated from the original question with that last comment. I got distracted. I'll have to leave it for someone else to answer I'm afraid.