# Android Google Keyboard crashes when capturing KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER

Tags: android

I'm trying to manage the `Next` event on the Google Keyboard on a Google Nexus 5. I want my application to check user information when the `Next` button gets pressed.

The code looks like this:

```
 private TextView.OnEditorActionListener GenerateEditorListeners()
{
    return new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL  && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                if (!finished)
                {
                    if (CheckUserInfo()) finished = true;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

On a Samsung Galaxy S4 works perfect, but on a Google Nexus 5 the **actionId = 0** and the **event = null**. So I figure out that the Samsung keyboard works fine with this code, but doesn't happen the same with the Google Keyboard.

Any idea on why it's not wokring for Google's keyboards?

**EDIT:** I've read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419766/how-to-capture-soft-keyboard-input-in-a-view) post that Google keyboard has a bug in some LatinIME keyboards.... I'm using a latin one. If that's the problem, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by using the `OnKeyListener` event:

```
 textUserEmail.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                if (!finished)
                {
                    if (CheckUserInfo()) finished = true;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Now it works in all keyboards.